# Integrate $\int\frac{x+1}{(x^2+7x-3)^3}dx$

Tags: integration, partial-fractions

How can i solve something like that?

$$\int\frac{x+1}{(x^2+7x-3)^3}dx$$

How should I start? Should I try rewrite it in partial fractions?

Comment: This is quite simple. Modify the numerator so as to get a form of derivative of denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

As $x^2+7x-3=\dfrac{(2x+7)^2-61}4$ start with $2x+7=\sqrt{61}\sec y$

Alternatively,

as the highest power of $x$ in $(x^2+7x-3)^2$ is $4,$

differentiate  $\dfrac{ax^3+bx^2+cx+d}{(x^2+7x-3)^2}$  wrt $x$

and compare with $\dfrac{x+1}{(x^2+7x-3)^3}$

Comment: How you know that you need use subs: $2x+7 = \sqrt{61}\sec y$ ?

Comment: @DavidM, See http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/trigsub/trigsub.html